# index property, definition and difference with event object

Tags: javascript, jquery

While learning jquery, I saw this example:

```
 $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

My first question is what the index property exactly does. In this example it is pretty obvious, but I have also seen an example like this **delay(700 * index)**. What does the index property do here?

My second question might be a bit vague, but I'll try to be as clear as possible. In the function parentheses, you can also use the event object as a parameter, and by my understanding you can give it whichever name you'd like. So, how does the interpreter know that the index parameter, isn't just the name I gave to the event object?

Comment: `event` object is only available in event listener callbacks...not in `each`. Arguments for `each` callback are explained in the docs http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand that the `each` function takes a callback function as an argument. This callback function also accepts an argument - *index* which in this case will be the index number of the `<li>` element.

So for instance if you have 4 `<li>` elements, the `each` function will create 4 iterations, each iteration will increment the *index* argument, starting from 0.

Another important thing to understand is that the index argument is not something that you have control over, it is defined in the `each` function - it's not that if you'd change its name to *event* it would actually change the object that has been passed in that callback. You can call it *i* or *event* for that matter and it will still be the index. The *event* argument is something that is passed by callback functions in Event Listeners such as `onmousedown`, `onclick` etc..

Hope this helps

---

**Update**

Here is how you would use the click event for all `<li>` elements..

```js
$('li').click(function(event){
  console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>I am the first List element</li>
  <li>I am the second List element</li>
  <li>I am the third List element</li>
  <li>I am the fourth List element</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that really did help. But my only remaining question is how you you would then make an Event Listener for a nod using the the each function. Would it be something like this                                                        $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
}).on('click' , function(){};

Comment: Sure... Well that depends on what event you want to attach to? What interaction are you expecting to happen with these `<li>` elements? What interactions do you want to respond to: A click, a hover?

Comment: I want it to respond to a 'click'   so the code must contain something like this       .on('click', function)